# SiteName in a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

I'm sure it's obvious, but how do I get the current site name from within a plugin?

I tried a few things, including

```
craft()->systemSettings->getSettings('general')
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

From searching the files (i.e. 'craft/app/Craft.php' line 124) it looks like you can get it using:

```
craft()->getSiteName()
```

Comment: Or, as with most things Craft, without the method call `craft()->siteName`.